# Spring MVC Multipart request with only xml in payload and Boundaries

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I'm trying to achieve something that even though I know is not what the Spring functionality is strictly meant for I would believe it can be done but I just cannot make it happen.

Basically, Having the following Spring MVC controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mime")
public class MimeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {"multipart/*"}, produces = {"text/plain"})
    public String executeSampleService(@RequestParam("json") String json, @RequestParam("xml") String xml ) {
        return "reached";
    }
}
```

**When I try pushing the following request from postman:**

```
Request Headers:
content-type:"multipart/related; boundary=Ramya"
cache-control:"no-cache"
postman-token:"559ba32f-97f8-423b-b1bb-283ec1d7856c"
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.1.1"
accept:"*/*"
host:"localhost:8080"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
content-length:269
Request Body:"--Ramya Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json" Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 {"json":"payload"} --Ramya Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml" Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 <xmlModel><test>blah</test></xmlModel> --Ramya-- "
```

I cannot seem to get anything beyond the following Exception:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1519833131951,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
    "message": "Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly",
    "path": "/mime/test"
}
```

I'm aware I'm trying to use a functionality intended for forms and files to be uploaded, but I can achieve the same in jersey following the suggestions here:

[Spring boot multipart/related mime type support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838926/spring-boot-multipart-related-mime-type-support)

I've tried changing the headers for the content type trying to match it to multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed but I still have no luck, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using `@FormDataParam` instead of  `@RequestParam` .

Comment: Wish it had worked...didn't do the trick, plus that's jersey jars, trying to achieve the same in spring...thanks anyway!